# AnyLogic: Select specific resource set based on condition

Tags: anylogic

I have created a simple model in AnyLogic (see screenshot). Now I want to add a condition that selects one of the two resource sets in the service block. As an example the following scenario shall apply: If there are more than 5 parts in the queue, worker 3 and worker 4 should perform the service. If there are <= 5 parts in the queue, the service shall be performed by worker 1 and worker 2. This is only meant to be a simplified example. I am primarily interested in solving this problem using a condition. I have already tried different approaches, but without success. Does anyone have an idea how the Java code for this condition could look like?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the queue since the service block already has a queue... So For this particular example in your resource choice conditions you will do the following:

```
service.queueSize()>5 ? (worker3.containsUnit(unit) || worker4.containsUnit(unit))
:
(worker1.containsUnit(unit) || worker2.containsUnit(unit))
```

You can change service.queueSize() with queue.size() if you insist in using a queue. After that you need to be sure to recalculate the conditions when needed, for this particular example i think you only need to recalculate them on exit action of the service block:

```
self.recalculateResourceChoiceConditions();
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy approach is to use `Seize` and `Delay` (and `Release` once done) blocks instead of `Service`. Before `Seize`, you can place your condition in a `SelectOutputOut` block. Like this:

[image]

Comment: for this case there's no benefit of using seize-delay-release compared to using a service, and using a selectoutput doesn't account for the changing dynamics of the queues... for instance when the queue size is 3 and you go to one output the service queue can increase to 6 easily and then it's too late, you already made the wrong flow choice

Comment: That's not an issue if you have two different queues after the selectOutputOut. You just evaluate the situation before entering the queues

Comment: imagine an agent is being processed in delay 2 and another in delay3, meanwhile 4 agents come and enter seize2 queue, then 5 agents come and enter seize4 queue... nothing else comes... after a while you will have 1 agent in seize4 queue and that agent will use worker 3 and 4 because you chose to go to that route a long time ago, even though there are less than 5 agents in the queue...